# read_csv not happening line by line

Tags: ansible

I am trying to read a csv file. However, during print its not reading line by line instead its going over some internal loop and duplicating results.

```yaml
- name: read csv
  read_csv:
    path: /u00/app/monitor/newrelic_test.csv
    key: Application   
  register: newrelic

- name: Print newrelic var   
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    var: newrelic.list
```

output looks lke below:

```
  [testserver1] =>
"newrelic.list": 
        "Application": "Microsoft",
        "env": "Test",
        "Datacenter": "DC1",
        "Hostname": "testserver1",
    },
        "Application": "Apple",
        "env": "Test",
        "Datacenter": "DC2",
        "Hostname": "testserver2",
    }
[testserver2] => {
"newrelic.list": 
    {
        "Application": "Microsoft",
        "env": "Test",
        "Datacenter": "DC1",
        "Hostname": "testserver1",
    },
        "Application": "Apple",
        "env": "Test",
        "Datacenter": "DC2",
        "Hostname": "testserver2",
    }
]
```

csv file:

```
Application,env,Datacenter,Hostname
Microsoft,Test,DC1,testserver1
Apple,Test,DC2,testserver2
```

Expected result shall be:

```
[testserver1] =>
"newrelic.list": 
        "Application": "Microsoft",
        "env": "Test",
        "Datacenter": "DC1",
        "Hostname": "testserver1",
    }
[testserver2] => {
"newrelic.list": 
    {
        "Application": "Apple",
        "env": "Test",
        "Datacenter": "DC2",
        "Hostname": "testserver2",
    }
]
```

**Edit : - Next block**

```yaml
- name: copy template
  template:
    src: /u00/ansible/Playbooks/files/infra-config.yml_template
    dest: /u00/app/monitor/infra-config.yml
  loop: "{{ newrelic.list }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: item
```

Issue: if `newrelic.list` is not been used then get error as below:

```
[testserver1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Invalid data passed to 'loop', it requires a list, got this instead: {'dict':
```

I tried adding `dict2items` but then template not able to read items.

Comment: It would help if you could replace the Ansible output in your question with output that doesn't contain all the terminal formatting codes.

Comment: larsks - I have removed terminal formatting which was coming from Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

The `read_csv` module doesn't read a CSV file "line by line"; from [the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/read_csv_module.html):

> Read[s] a CSV file and return[s] a list or a dictionary, containing one dictionary per row.

So when you run this task:

```
- name: read csv
  read_csv:
    path: data.csv
    key: Application
  register: newrelic
```

You get a variable `newrelic` which has an empty `list` element and a `dict` element containing the data from the CSV file, keyed by `Application` (because that's what you asked for). If use a `debug` task to look at the value of `newrelic`, we see:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "newrelic": {
        "changed": false,
        "dict": {
            "Apple": {
                "Application": "Apple",
                "Datacenter": "DC2",
                "Hostname": "testserver2",
                "env": "Test"
            },
            "Microsoft": {
                "Application": "Microsoft",
                "Datacenter": "DC1",
                "Hostname": "testserver1",
                "env": "Test"
            }
        },
        "failed": false,
        "list": []
    }
}
```

It's not clear exactly what you're trying to do here, but if you want to look up values from your CSV file by inventory hostname, you would need to key it by `Hostname` instead:

```
- name: read csv
  read_csv:
    path: data.csv
    key: Hostname
  register: newrelic
```

And then you could write:

```
- name: Print newrelic var
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    var: newrelic.dict[inventory_hostname]
```

Assuming you have hosts `testserver1` and `testserver2` in your inventory, a playbook like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: read csv
      read_csv:
        path: data.csv
        key: Hostname
      register: newrelic

- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Print newrelic var
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: hostvars.localhost.newrelic.dict[inventory_hostname]
```

Would result in this output:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [read csv] ****************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

PLAY [all] *********************************************************************

TASK [Print newrelic var] ******************************************************
ok: [testserver1] => {
    "hostvars.localhost.newrelic.dict[inventory_hostname]": {
        "Application": "Microsoft",
        "Datacenter": "DC1",
        "Hostname": "testserver1",
        "env": "Test"
    }
}
ok: [testserver2] => {
    "hostvars.localhost.newrelic.dict[inventory_hostname]": {
        "Application": "Apple",
        "Datacenter": "DC2",
        "Hostname": "testserver2",
        "env": "Test"
    }
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
testserver1                : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
testserver2                : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: larsks: you are right, i have next block to update template and copy to remote servers.
- name: copy template
  template:
    src: /u00/ansible/Playbooks/files/infra-config.yml_template
    dest: /u00/app/monitor/infra-config.yml
  loop: "{{ newrelic.list }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: item

issue is I get same entry in both testserver1 and testserver2 instead of above read value.

Comment: It's better to add additional to your question, where you can format it properly, rather than leaving it in a comment. In your comment you seem to be referring to `newlist.list`, but as I discussed in this answer, there is no data in `newrelic.list`.

Comment: larsks - edited the question and added what is next block and what result i am getting.

Comment: When using the `key` argument to `read_csv`, I don't get any data in `newrelic.list`; using the `key` arguments gets me a dictionary instead. Since I appear to be seeing different behavior than you I'm not sure I can help beyond what I've shown in this answer.

Comment: larsks - thanks for support. till reading from csv and debug, it works as expected. but when I push this data to template then this got wrong. either i get same items in both servers or I get error that template attributes not found.